# Does WSO2 ELB use any Cloud Service Cluster (IaaS) internally?

Tags: openstack, wso2, iaas

How does WSO2 ELB pull information from a Cloud Service Cluster (IaaS) such as OpenStack in order to perform auto-scaling? Does WSO2 ELB make use of any Cloud Service Cluster internally? If it does, what IaaS vendor is implemented out-of-the-box?

Does WSO2 even pull any information at all? Does it just require the host machines to be in a cluster in order for the worker/manager or auto-scaling algorithm to work?

Thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WSO2 ELB](http://wso2.com/products/elastic-load-balancer/) supports IaaS integration using jclouds APIs. Theoretically this means we can support any IaaS that is supported by jclouds. Currently we provide support for AWS EC2 and Openstack-nova IaaS providers. Please read more info on autoscaling using WSO2 ELB from [here](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ELB203/Auto-Scaling+in+Load+Balancer).

Download our latest release (WSO2 ELB 2.0.3) from our product page.